# How to set JSlider parameter from 0 to 1 that can return floats

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I'm trying to modified this JSLider function

```
  public JSlider getSlider(int min, int max, int init, int mjrTkSp, int mnrTkSp) {
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, min, max, init);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(mjrTkSp);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(mnrTkSp);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider.addChangeListener(new SliderListener());
        return slider;
      }
```

I would like to set a range of min 0 and max 1 but I want to be able to return 0.1 , 0.2 , 0.3 to maximum 1 ( depends on the user slide value )

So I tried `sliderR = getSlider(0, 1, 0, 50, 5);`

Unfortunately this will only return 0 OR 1 , but I want to be able to return 0 , 0.1 0.2 0.3 etc..

Thank you

Comment: Consider using a `JSpinner` with a `double` based [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html#SpinnerNumberModel-double-double-double-double-) instead.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was thinking about that , but I will forced to cast a lot of things witch won't be ideal

Comment: *"but I will forced to cast a lot of things"* Why? Are you aware of `SpinnerNumberModel.getNumber().doubleValue()`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for elaborating , but some boxes are expecting floats and there are many attributes initialized in floats so I will probably have to try casting (float) SpinnerNumberModel.getNumber().doubleValue() , wich might work

Comment: No need for casting, but good time for checking the documentation.. `SpinnerNumberModel.getNumber().floatValue()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is the following: instead of stepping by 0.1 from 0 to 1, step by 1 from 0 to 10. Then, simply divide the value by 10 e.g. in the `ChangeListener` or whereever you need that value.

Comment: Yup ! That was just what I was going to do ,haha